# What is the default sort parameter set for directories and how to change it?

Tags: ubuntu, file

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.  In a directory I have around 12,00,000 images.  The images are named with ascending order numeric values such as:

```
1234567890.jpg
1234567891.jpg
....

1245367890.jpg
```

I believe, that the images were ordered in a sequence sorted by their names.  But the program that I ran to process the images had picked up random files.  This makes me believe that the files in that particular folder is not sorted by name but by the time of copying into the server or may be by their size.

How could i set the default file sort parameter for a directory to name in Ubuntu?

Comment: See [`man 3 readdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html): "The order in which filenames are read by successive calls to readdir() depends on the filesystem implementation; it is unlikely that the names will be sorted in any fashion." `ls` may nicely sort output for you, but that's not the general case. The rest depends on what exactly you're using here. Bash? Python? C?

Comment: Thank you.  I am using Python.

Comment: Is this a question about a program you have written? If it's a shell script it's probably on-topic here in [unix.se], otherwise it's better your question is migrated to [so]. In either case you need to provide more detail about the situation.

Comment: @roaima  I believe this question is about shell script and not about python programming.  While I agree with @muru first comment about `ls` nicely sorting the output.  However, that happens when you actually try to read the contents of a directory.  I want to understand what is the default sorting/storing structure within Linux directories.  I don't think it would be completely random for any and every directory and hence the question here.

Answer (score 0):

There's very little information in the question on which to base an answer so since you're here on [*Unix & Linux* SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) I'm assuming you're referring to shell scripting. If you care to provide more details a more targeted answer may be possible.

Within a shell script you'd typically iterate across directory entries using a globbing wildcard, which implicitly sorts the files according to your locale (usually alphanumerically):

```
for item in *; do echo "Got $item"; done
```

The `ls` program also has built-in sort functionality, but you can disable this with the `-f` flag (see `man ls`):

```
ls -f
```

The `find` command iterates across unsorted directories, leaving it to the user to sort the output if required:

```
find . -maxdepth 1
```

Programmatically you or your library would use `opendir(3)` and `readdir(3)`, which operate on unsorted directory entries.

There isn't really a concept of adding a sort criterion to a directory itself (although I believe some filesystems do prefer sorted directories).